# Textview width is not the fit the width of the parent

Tags: width, android-linearlayout, textview, android

I couldn't make equal width of Textview and linearlayout. Although I set width match_parent in Textview it doesn't fit with the parent width.

I saw these posts :
[Android textView width not increasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541874/android-textview-width-not-increasing)

[Android TextView does not expand to match parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603055/android-textview-does-not-expand-to-match-parent)

[TextView width match drawableTop width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620723/textview-width-match-drawabletop-width)

[How to adjust text font size to fit textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview/3378422#3378422)

[How to adjust text font size to fit textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview)

But my problem isn't resolved

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/defaultpicpic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/textViewItemStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my problem by wrapping the views in a `LinearLayout` and followed by a small `View` beneath.

It is not clear why this worked.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/textViewItemStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2px" />

</LinearLayout>
```